# Pantalla de Seleccion RadioButton

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, radiobutton

Quiero implementar un menú de selección que me muestre una lista de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
        No se con que tipo de actividad se pueda implementar algo asi en Android Studio, 
muchas gracias

Comment: ¿La necesitas que aparezca por encima de los demás elementos?

Comment: Si.. que al seleccionar vuelva a ocultarse

Answer (score 0):

eso esta hecho con un MultiSelectionSpinner.

Mirate esta pagina, donde te sale un ejemplo:

https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Algo como lo que quieres y sencillo seria esto:

En el archivo activity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.058" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.042" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

En el archivo MainActivity.java

```
//Implementas AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

//Array de strings con los nombres de lo que quieras.
private String[] miArray = {"Cuenca", "Quito", "Guayaquil", "Ibarra", "PortoViejo", "Loja", "Ambato", "Salinas", "Manta"};
//Objeto desplegable.
private Spinner miLista;
//Creas un adaptador.
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
String nombreCiudad;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Casting del elemento spinner.
    miLista = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    miLista.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Instancia y paso de parametros para constructor.
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, miArray);
    //Cargo el adaptador al spinner.
    miLista.setAdapter(adaptador);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner:
            //Creo una variable de tipo string para guardar el string y postion buscará la ciudad dentro
            // del array que coincida para almacenarla.
            nombreCiudad = miArray[position];

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, nombreCiudad, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

  }
}
```

Cuando lo selecciones te enseñara la selección con un Toast.

[image: Imagen con listado]

[image: Selección de imágen]

Comment: Muy completa y clara tu respuesta, de verdad gracias..